# Problem connecting real Android device to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I just got a new computer and am trying to set up my developing environment but I'm having trouble getting eclipse to connect with my phone. I have a HTC Aria android device and I was able to use it with eclipse on my old Windows XP computer. On my new Windows 7 64bit computer though, its not working.

When I run my program, I see my HTC device in the device chooser, however, its state is "offline" and it randomly disappears then reappears. I can select it, but I cannot push "OK" to run on the device. I've tried reinstalling my driver and updating it through HTC's website, but nothing has changed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling my OS, installing Eclipse Indigo 64bit, and then installing my phone driver. Works perfectly now. Have no idea what was wrong before